# Niederlassungserlaubnis, Freelancing and Citizenship in Germany

Tags: germany, citizenship, freelance, unemployment-benefits

I am an IT professional living in Germany for the last 6 years. I recently got my Niederlassungserlaubnis.

My employment terminated and I will be unemployed in a month.

Do I need to inform Auslanderbehorde about any changes in employment?

Secondly, I am planning to do freelancing in short/long term and I want to apply for German citizenship this year.

Does taking up freelancing activity affect my citizenship application, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

- The *Niederlassungserlaubnis* is a *permanent* residence title, § 9 ⑴ 1 [AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/index.html), and as such it never expires.
  (There are nonetheless various conditions that revoke your title, § 51 AufenthG, e. g. you become a big‑time criminal.)
  There are **no further obligations to inform the immigration office**.

  You should inform the Federal Employment Agency (*Bundesagentur für Arbeit*) about impending unemployment (at best 3 months in advance, unless you received a pink slip later), though, but that’s *independent* from aliens law.
- For original naturalization, you will need to prove you can support yourself and your dependents, § 10 ⑴ 1 № 3 [StAG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stag/index.html).
  It isn’t prescribed as to how to prove that:
  You could be filthy rich and live off of your capital earnings.

  At any rate, with respect to minimum income you should *not be eligible* for social welfare benefits according to Social Code 2 (today’s marketing name *Bürgergeld*) or Social Code 12 (in particular *Grundsicherung im Alter oder bei Erwerbsminderung*, commonly clipped to the ambiguous term *Grundsicherung*), unless it’d constitute undue hardship.

  The *circumstance* of **self‑employment *alone* does not affect your chances to citizenship** but if you are *just starting* your business, its revenue may in all likelihood be below the necessary subsistence level.